# How to sort list elements by specific indexes of specific values in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, sorting, dataset

I have a Dataset of 500000 3D coordinates and 500000 of rgb patches. First I want to sort the 3D coordinates to have the most similar values at the beginning after removing some wrong data from the dataset. For that I have proceeded as follows :

```py
# Loading saved Dataset
print("Begin Loding Dataset ...")
X = np.load('train_RGB-Patches_Fire_seq01.npy')
Y = np.load('train_3DPoses-Patches_Fire_seq01.npy')
print("End Loading Dataset => Shapes : ",X.shape, Y.shape)
print("max - min 3D originals : ",Y.max()," , ", Y.min())
print("Begin Correcting 3D_Patches Dataset ...")
Y_faux_indx = np.unique(np.argwhere(Y>15)[:,0].reshape((-1,1)))
Y_correct = np.delete(Y,Y_faux_indx,0)
X_correct = np.delete(X,Y_faux_indx,0)
Y_sorted = np.array(sorted(Y_correct.tolist())).reshape((-1,4))
print("End Correcting 3D_Patches Dataset ...")
```

Now according to the sorted 3D labels, I want to get the indexes of these sorted data from the previous unsorted corrected data  and then arrange the rgb data according of these indexes. for that I made this code which takes a very large time to execute:

```
print("Begin Sorting 3D_Patches Dataset ...")
sorted_dataset_indx = []
for j in range(len(Y_sorted)):
    element_verification = Y_correct == Y_sorted[j]
    for i in range(len(element_verification)):
        if element_verification[i].prod()==1:
            if i not in sorted_dataset_indx:
                sorted_dataset_indx.append(i)
 sorted_dataset_indx = np.array(sorted_dataset_indx)
 X_sorted = X_correct[sorted_dataset_indx]
 print("End Sorting 3D_Patches Dataset => Shapes : ",X_sorted.shape,Y_sorted.shape)
 print("max - min 3D new : ",Y_sorted.max()," , ", Y_sorted.min())
```

So I want another solution that will help me to execute this faster?

Comment: Provide an example of your dataset (10 records) and shorten your code to just the part that is giving you trouble, to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Wrt _"sort the 3D coordinates to have the most similar values"_ - what is "similar" by your definition? Smallest absolute difference? MSR?

Comment: @aneroid I think it doesn't matter. He's asking about the next step of the process being described...

Comment: aneroid thank you for your answer, indeed as @Shlomif said, I asked about the second part of the process. The answer given works well after some little modifications to adapt to my use-case. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using loops - and especially nested loops - is generally gonna be slow and should be avoided where possible.
I can't reproduce your code obviously, but here's a toy example for adaptation to your use-case:

```
list1 = [1, 10, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1.5]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
enumerated_list1 = list(enumerate(list1))
enumerated_list1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
sorting_inds = [x[0] for x in enumerated_list1]
list2_sorted_by_list1 = [list2[i] for i in sorting_inds]
```

Comment: I just edited the lambda sorting function to sort according to multi-dimension array ( 3d coords ), like that ' enumerated_list1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].tolist()) '